# Add information about linking your accounts, on migrated questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

Every few weeks there is another [user complaining about not being able edit their questions / answers, after the question gets migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14003/edit-answer-given-in-stackoverflow).

The answer to this is always the same: "[Associate your accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14003/edit-answer-given-in-stackoverflow/14012#14012)".

---

I think that there should be something on the originating question that tells users to associate their accounts.

This feature could be visible to only people who have asked the question, or have answered that question, or it could always be visible.

---

This, **I hope**, will relieve some of the confusion about migrated questions.

Comment: Those two links, were from the most recent case.

Comment: The "Associate your Accounts" link is broken ... which means I still don't know how to do it lol

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it currently looks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree. I think that a few features should be explained a little bit more to anonymous or first time users. Bounties, Migration, Accepting answers, should all probably get a little 1 or two sentence explanation. I'd suggest putting them where the current migrated messages are, and they can only be seen by the question asker.

Comment: The one I reference, was from a user who posted an answer, to a question that go migrated.